# Populate files inside a pre-made folder in Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like this code to populate the files uploaded by the user to a set folder in Google Drive, not create a new folder each time. How do I do this?

See pre-existing code below:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {
  try {
    var dropbox = form.myName + ", " + form.myBusiness;
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName + ", " + form.myBusiness + ", " + form.details);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();
  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you have should do exactly that. Have you inspected the results of `DriveApp.getFoldersByName(<your variable>)`? Who does this code execute as?

Comment: What this does at the moment is create a new folder directly into Goolge drive's main desktop if you like. What I would like it to do is populate the files and anything else uploaded into a pre existing folder which I could share with other users, so they too can see the files inside. If you were to upload two different things with the same name and organisation, it would work perfectly, however this is going out to multiple people with different names etc. Meaning it would generate a new folder in Drive separate from the other, which is great, I just need it to be inside a folder itself.

Comment: Also, this is being executed as "me (my email address)". And the people who have access to the app are "anyone, even anonymous".

Comment: It wasn't clear from your post that you wanted all responses to the form to be in the same folder regardless of the respondents' details. In the future, try to include example outputs, e.g. "these files should all be uploaded to the folder 'My form A/<specific respondent folder>,' instead of 'My Drive/<specific respondent folder>'"

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. Change the dropbox var to the folder name that the files should be uploaded to. This file name needs to be exactly the same in GDrive and in the code. Example:

```
var dropbox = "Example file name";
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
```